# using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported (XCode)

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an XCode (Swift) project which is using native static lib (Swift) and this lib uses another native static lib (C++)

> static lib A (C++) -> static lib B (Swift) -> MyProject

first of all, in order to be able to use methods from lib A in lib B, I need to set the `bridge` file in the `BuildSettings`, right? then I am free to use any methods from A in B, ok.

If I try to build the lib B with `Build libraries for distribution = NO`, everything is compiling and works, but if I need to change this value to `YES` (in order to distribute the lib as Release ver) I get the error

> error: using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported

After a little google I found a few possible solutions on SO where most of them suggest setting `Build libraries for distribution = NO`, but this solution looks for me as a workaround, because in order to distribute the lib as a Release version you need to set it as `YES`.

Then I found another solution

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/10419

but here one explains that

> You'll need to remove the bridging header from where you added it in the Build Settings, in order to get your framework to compile.

But I can't remove the `bridge` file as if I remove it I don't be able to use lib A in my lib B.

So, what is the proper solution here?

Comment: if you use C++ in libA, maybe you can wrapper it with Objective C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can not use bridging header in a swift framework, but there is some workaround. Use Module!

1. create module map file for libA.
   for example, lib A is

```
@interface LibA : NSObject
+ (void)testA;
@end
```

so you can create map file like this:

```
module LibA {
    header "LibA.h"
    export *
}
```

just be careful the path

```
header "xxx/libA.h",
```

2. Set the build setting search paths for frameworkB

add search paths in `Build Settings` - `Swift Compiler - Search Paths` - `Import Paths`

`$(SRCROOT)/FrameworkB/`

3. use LibA in frameworkB

[full example in github](https://github.com/wzio/TestFramework)